# Golang: Как вернуть неопределённое количество значений из функции?

Tags: golang

Господа, подскажите, как в Go можно реализовать функцию, возвращающую неопределённое количество значений?

Должно в итоге получиться что-то такое:

```
func test() (магия) {
    for _, t := range tickers {
        return t.name
    }
}
```

Comment: может вы хотите вернуть массив строк?

Comment: Было бы неплохо, но как это можно сделать из цикла?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
func test()[]string {
    var result []string = make([]string, len(tickers))

    for i, t:= range tickers {
        result[i] = t.name;
    }

    return result
}
```